# DependencyProperty in UserControl not binding in ListItem Template

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, dependency-properties

Ok hours of google searching and stakoverflow reading, I have been unable to find the answer to this issue.
I have a `UserControl` that is used to show a `ProgressBar` with a `DependencyProperty` of type `double`.

The MainPage.XAML.cs contains the `DataContext`:

```
void MainPage_Loaded(object sender,RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        setDataContext();
        MainGameListBox.ItemsSource = vm.GameList;
}
```

This is whats in the MainPage.XAML:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" x:Name="MainGameListBox"
         SelectionChanged="listBoxGameSearch_SelectionChanged" >
    <!-- set its ItemsPanel to be a WrapPanel -->
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <toolkit1:WrapPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <toolkit1:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                    <toolkit1:ContextMenu>
                        <toolkit1:MenuItem Header="Pin to start" Click="PinGameToStart_Click" />
                    </toolkit1:ContextMenu>
                </toolkit1:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                <Grid Width="173" Height="173"
                      Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Margin="12">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="32"/>                                    
                        <RowDefinition Height="32"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="32"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="32"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="86.5"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="86.5"/>    
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="0" Width="64"
                            Height="64" BorderBrush="#70BC1F" BorderThickness="2"
                            Margin="6,6,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <Image  Source="{Binding GameTile,
                                Converter={StaticResource imageCacheConverter}}" />
                    </Border>
                    <view:CircularProgressChart x:Name="circularProgChart"
                                                Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                                                Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                                Margin="6"
                                                Loaded="CircularProgressChart_Loaded"
                                                CompletionPercent="{Binding CompletionPercentage}" />
                </Grid>           
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The `CompletionPercent` is the DP and the `UserControl` is below:

```
public partial class CircularProgressChart:UserControl
{

    public double CompletionPercent
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(CompletionPercentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CompletionPercentProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CompletionPercentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CompletionPercent", typeof(double), typeof(CircularProgressChart), new PropertyMetadata(0.0, CompletionPercentChanged));

    public CircularProgressChart()
    {
        try
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the `CompletionPercentage` Property:

```
public class Progress : INotifyPropertyChanged
{ 
    private double _completionPercentage = 0.0;
    public double CompletionPercentage
    {
        get{return _completionPercentage;}
        set{
            _completionPercentage = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CompletionPercentage");
        }
    }
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

Question, is why is the 
    `CompletionPercent="{Binding CompletionPercentage}"`
not being bound?  It gets the default value 0, but when the `CompletionPercentage` is updated the DP doesn't get the update.  I've checked the `NotifyPropertyChanged` method and it fires correctly and works in all other parts of code.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is `DataContext = this` line in `CircularProgressChart` constructor. `{Binding CompletionPercentage}` looks for `CompletionPercentage` property in `DataContext`, which obviously does not exist in `CircularProgressChart`. Instance of `Progress` class never makes it's way to the `CircularProgressChart` (explicit assignment of dependency property has a priority over binding).

**Solution 1** (if you really want to keep dependency property): remove the `DataContext = this;` line. If you need to bind to properties of `CircularProgressChart` in it's XAML, specify correct binding sources instead of relying on `DataContext`.

**Solution 2** (very common when deriving from `UserControl`): remove `CompletionPercent` dependency property completely (including its binding in `MainPage.xaml`) and bind to `CompletionPercentage` directly in `CircularProgressChart.xaml`. Also remove `DataContext = this;` line.

**Solution 3** (true WPF-way): use default `ProgressBar` control with a custom template instead of creating your own control.